# Password count help

Tags: c++, loops, passwords

```
void getPassword()
{
  while (true)
  {
    string password;
    cout << "Enter the password: ";
    getline(cin, password);

  if (password == "123456") break;
  cout << "INVALID. ";
  } // while
} // getPassword 



int main()
{
  getPassword();

  double P;
  double r;
  double N = 360;
  double rate; 


  cout << "What's the mortgage amount? ";
  cin >> P;
  cin.ignore(1000, 10);  

  cout << "What's the annual interest rate? ";
  cin >> r;
  cin.ignore(1000, 10); 

  rate = r / 100 / 12; 

  // (p * (1 + r)n * r) / ((1 + r)n - 1)
  double M = P * ((pow))(1 + rate, N) * rate / (((pow))(1 + rate, N) -1);

  cout.setf(ios::fixed|ios::showpoint); 
  cout << setprecision(2);

  cout << "Principal = $" << P <<  endl;

  cout.unsetf(ios::fixed|ios::showpoint);
  cout << setprecision(6); // resets precision to its default 
  cout << "Interest Rate = " << r << "%" << endl; 
  cout << "Amortization Period = " << N / 12 << " years" << endl;

  cout << "The monthly payment = $" << M << endl;


  ofstream fout;
  fout.open("mortgages.txt", ios::app);
  if (!fout.good()) throw "I/O error";
  fout.setf(ios::fixed|ios::showpoint); 
  fout << setprecision(2);

  fout << "Principal = $" << P <<  endl;

  fout.unsetf(ios::fixed|ios::showpoint);
  fout << setprecision(6); // resets precision to its default 
  fout << "Interest Rate = " << r << "%" << endl; 
  fout << "Amortization Period = " << N / 12 << " years" << endl;

  fout << "The monthly payment = $" << M << endl;
  fout.close(); 

  return 0;
}
```

What's up guys? I have a homework assignment for comsc and I have hit a roadblock in my last program. What I am attempting to do is limit the user of this program to 3 invalid password attempts. Do I need to change this to a value-returning subprogram or can I accomplish this without doing so? Any help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way would be to change `getPassword` so that it returns a `bool` that signifies whether the user put in the right password.  Then, rather than `while (true)`, say `for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)`...and rather than `break`, `return true`.  After the loop, `return false` since they went 3 rounds without putting in the right password.

In the rest of the program, rather than just calling `getPassword`, check its return value.  If it's false, print an error message and exit.

Something like:

```
bool checkPassword() {  // renaming this, since it doesn't just *get* a password
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        string password;
        std::cout << "Enter password: " << std::flush;
        std::getline(std::cin, password);
        if (password == "123456") return true;
        std::cout << "INVALID.\n";
    }
    std::cout << "Maximum attempts exceeded.\n";
    return false;
}

int main() {
    if (!checkPassword()) {
        return 1;
    }

    ... rest of main() here ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I have not yet learned how to use the boolean technique lol. So sorry for the stupid questions, but this is what I have modified it to. After the third attempt now it continues into main but is there anyway I can prevent this from happening and closing the program
    void getPassword()
    {
      int i; 
      i = 0; 
      while (i<3)
      {
        i = i + 1;
        string password;
        cout << "Enter the password: ";
        getline(cin, password);
 
        if (password == "1285136") break;
        cout << "INVALID. ";
      } // while
    } // getPassword

Comment: The "boolean technique" is nothing special.  You return a `bool` (which is either `true` or `false`), the same way you'd return an `int` or whatever.  The caller then checks that value and acts on it.  See my edit for an example.

Comment: If you really really wanted to, you could call `exit(1)` from `getPassword`, in which case you wouldn't have to return a value.  But i hate doing that, for various reasons...one being that in my opinion, subroutines shouldn't `exit`.  It's up to `main` to decide when and how to end the program.

Comment: Ok I now understand bool and am so close! With your help it now works properly except once I input the correct password, it prompts me to do so once more. After the second correct password it breaks into main and runs accordingly. Is there any way I can do so by only inputting the password once? Thank you so much for your help so far by the way!

Comment: Make sure you only have *one* call to `getPassword` (or `checkPassword`, or whatever) in `main`.  When i say `... rest of main() here ...`, i don't mean the `getPassword` call you had... :)  That first `if` *replaces* the `getPassword` call you had before.